# WLAN adapter on Ubuntu Server inside Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, hyper-v

I need to set up an Ubuntu server as a router. However we need to make it wireless and  wired. I need a WLAN adapter for the wireless part of the router.

I get my Internet connection on my server through my wireless adapter from my host but it automatically sees it as an Ethernet adapter instead of as a wireless adapter.

Is there any way of making a (virtual) wireless adapter on Ubuntu server 12.04 inside a hyper-v machine?